# Dividing listbox items into 2 parts

Tags: vb.net, list, split, listbox

I have a listbox with random items, I wanted to divide it into 2 part's and put each part in one listbox. I was able to do it, but i got a very messy code, couldn't found any help online, so I just wanna to ask if there is another way of doing it. Here's my code.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        'items count
        Dim count_listbox1 As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

        'half the count - 1 (im going to use it on the for loop)
        Dim metade_listbox1_1 As Integer = (count_listbox1 / 2) - 1

        'half the count
        Dim metade_listbox1_2 As Integer = (count_listbox1 / 2)


        ' ( first part of the listbox)
        For i = 0 To metade_listbox1_1
            list1.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Item(i)) 'list1 - listbox that contains 1 half
        Next

        ' (second part of the listbox items)
        For i = metade_listbox1_2 To count_listbox1
            list2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Item(i)) 'list2 - listbox that contains 2 half 
        Next

        'check if number of items its even or odd, if odd, deletes the first item of the list2, 
        'because its the same as the last item from list1
        If eo = False Then
            list2.Items.Remove(list2.Items.Item(0))
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are many ways to split the list. The following would distribute them evenly one by one

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        Dim lstbx As ListBox = If(i Mod 2 = 0, list1, list2)
        lstbx.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

An approach with a result more like yours would be this (requires importing `System.Linq`).
Note that I first set `size2` to the half of the count so that it will have the extra item in case the number of items is odd.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim size2 as Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count / 2
    Dim size1 as Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - size2

    list1.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.GetRange(0, size1))
    list2.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.GetRange(size1, size2))
End Sub
```

Comment: The first piece of code didn't work very good, the second, i get an error saying 'AddRange' is not a member of listbox. I have imported System.Linq

Comment: What is "not very good"? The order is different as it distributes the items one by one but I assumed that does not matter as your items are random anyway.
I updated the second example - it was missing a part of the code, sry.

Comment: Actually your first code it's working, i tried a few minutes ago and it was not, my bad. It's working fine, thanks for the help, a lot more professional.